# When I save as CSV, the file contains two separators which are comma and pipe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have two tables named result and result1 respectively. The only difference between those is with 'TITLE' columns, that one is str and another is str with the double quote. 
[table: result and result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0b0F.jpg)

My computer excel default is sep by ','. And the python to_csv default is also ','. And now when I check my result and result1 in CSV file by using the filter.

I want my whole file looks like this:

[result.csv sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UVrv.jpg)

But: There are some line looks like this:

[result.csv bad lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcKPs.jpg)

Have a closer look, I found out some line is separated by pipe?????:

[result.csv bad lines closer look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef7YG.jpg)

My questions become like:

1.why when I save as csv, the file is contain two separators which is comma and pipe.

2.How can I solve this problem? I check my data on python, it is all good.

Anybody can help?? I would be soooo appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your code? It might help in understanding the situation better.

Comment: Thank you. I already solved the problem. If pd.to_csv save the file with separator comma and pipe, the good ways fix it are: 1, open a new excel sheet. ==>2. click Data in the top ==>3. click 'get data' from top left.==>4. select data and to the page with a preview of your data. Chose 'Based on the entire dataset' under then Data Type Detection column.